# Automatically running tests using TypeScript and Mocha when any file changes

Tags: typescript, gulp, automated-tests, mocha.js, gulp-watch

I need to build a development environment which will automatically compile, run the tests and then TSLint when any `.ts` file in `./src/` or `./test/` changes, and print out the results of the tests and the lint.

```
./src/*.ts  --\   (tsc --watch)         (mocha --watch)
               |---------------> ./lib/ ---------------> console.log
./test/*.ts --/      |
                     |   (tslint --watch)
                     |--------------------> console.log
```

I've written npm scripts to run this work flow only once with `npm run test`:

```
// package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "pretest": "tsc", // will compile *.ts in src/ and test/ to lib/
    "test": "mocha --reporter spec --full-trace lib/test/tests.js",  // run the compiled test file
    "posttest": "gulp tslint"  // run gulp for tslint
  }
}
```

I wrote a gulp task to watch file changes to trigger the npm script:

```
// gulpfile.js
var exec = require('gulp-exec');
gulp.task("watch", () => {
  gulp.watch(paths.scripts, () => {
    exec(`npm run test`, {
      continueOnError: true,
      pipeStdout: true
    })
  });
});
```

I ran `gulp watch`, but I didn't show the results of test and lint in the console.

How to achieve my goal that it will run ts-compile, mocha-test, and then ts-lint when any `*.ts` file changes?

Comment: You have a typo in `scirpts`, it should be `scripts`.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to your tests directly in mocha, you would then have more granular control on your various tasks.

You could have the following tasks:

```
gulp.task('compileSrcForWatch', ['compileSrc'], () => gulp.start('test'));
gulp.task('compileTestForWatch', ['compileTest'], () => gulp.start('test'));

gulp.task('watchAndTest', () => {
    gulp.watch(config.inputSourceFiles, ['compileSrcForWatch']);
    gulp.watch(config.inputTestFiles, ['compileTestForWatch']);
});
```

I've created a gist with the whole file [here](https://gist.github.com/pyrho/d3916d33fe8415f5f181668afe69b763).